# bootstrap datepicker date-range not showing on calander

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I implemented bootstrap datepicker date-range in the below snippet but I don't see the range showing on the calendar after I have selected a date for start date and end date.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Page 2</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="input-group input-daterange">
  <input id="startDate1" name="startDate1" type="text"
   class="form-control" readonly="readonly"> <span
   class="input-group-addon"> <span
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span> <span class="input-group-addon">to</span> <input id="endDate1"
   name="endDate1" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
  <span class="input-group-addon"> <span
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>

 <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you need to add the bootstrap-datepicker css resource as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
```

and use the below syntax for date range.

```
 $('.input-daterange').datepicker({});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
  <script     
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Page 2</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="input-group input-daterange">
  <input id="startDate1" name="startDate1" type="text"
   class="form-control" readonly="readonly"> <span
   class="input-group-addon"> <span
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span> <span class="input-group-addon">to</span> <input id="endDate1"
   name="endDate1" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
  <span class="input-group-addon"> <span
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>

 <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
              });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```